# Take selection of AutocompleteBox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

This must be so simple that I don't see it.
How can I read the text of a selected item in a autocomplete-box?

When I type "Mi" and "Milk" gets completed in dropdown, "Mi" will be still
the text that is the value in autocomplete.text, although "Mi" gets
replaced with "Milk" visually in the textbox?

Answer (score 0):

use selectionchanged event to get the selected item. You may update the text of your autocomplete control to reflect selected item.

```
    private void SearchBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            string selecteditem = (string)e.AddedItems[0];
            this.SearchBox.Text = selecteditem;
        }
    }
```